# Authority Delegated SPL token transactions without a program

Tags: transactions, spl-token, authority, delegation

i want to use authority delegation so a user can delegate his tokens and later a transaction can be created to transfer those tokens. can this be done without a smart contract and can the authority be delegated to a publickey that only the app has access to and can perform transactions on the users behalf? if so how would i go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the delegate can be any `Pubkey`, the only requirement to achieve the transfer is for that key to be able to "sign", so adding a signature as an on curve keypair, or signing as a PDA using invoke_signed.

However, it doesn't seem very correct to delegate to anything else than a program as the user does not get any guarantee (the code).

Comment: when i try to delegate to a non program `PubKey` i get this error
`WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions`